# WP7 Silverlight: Data binding with the same XAML at design & runtime

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I'd like to use the same data at design and runtime in my WP7 application. The relevant part of the XAML looks like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=data.xaml}"
  DataContext="{Binding Source=???}"
```

This way I can see the data at design time. Is there a way to use the same data at runtime?

Comment: For the record, if you use the same static datasource, there's no reason to use the DesignTime DataContext.

Comment: OK, then this means that I'm too stupid to do it. All the examples I can find online bind to an object instance or a database. How can I bind to a XAML directly?

Answer (score 1):

Was not aware of the existence of d:DataContext. I dare to say:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=data.xaml}"
DataContext="{Binding Source=data.xaml}"
```

--- Edit added -------------------

Well... checking here and there found that, as expected, "DesignData" is not the same as "Binding" (I was misreading this, sorry). "DesignData" has the ability to instance, at design time, an object based on a xml file and this has no effect at runtime. The Binding we are try to build will never work, as its purpose is to use already instanced objects.

When you run the default template for panorama applications it instances its own data (check the code for MainViewModel.cs)... and that's why it shows is different from that in the xml file. All you have to do is, manually, open the xml in the "LoadData" method and load the file data so you can display the same at runtime and design time.

Comment: That was my first try. But it doesn't work. Don't know why, the UI is just blank. Part of the problem might be that, in order for d:DataContext to work the file data.xaml must use "DesignData" as build action.

Comment: Well... have to say I did the test with a single class with a simple property... the order of the attributes was irrelevant in my case. May I see your data.xaml file to try to test it?

Comment: It's the one from the "Windows Phone Panorama Application" template in Visual Studio 2010 (Beta2 refresh of the WP7 SDK). I added this line to MainPage.xaml 

`DataContext="{Binding Source=SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"`

and removed the data context changing code in the constructor and MainPage_Loaded.